# How to do a custom api call in a custom field?

Tags: react-admin

I'm new in react-admin and I need to create a custom field.

I want to get from an endpoint a list of information (for instance 3 objects).

Then I need to create on my custom Field (a component) 3 `NumberInput` (based on the list)

```
const CustomInput = () => (
    <div>
        <NumberInput source="foo" label="bar" />
        <NumberInput source="foo2" label="bar2" />
        <NumberInput source="foo3" label="bar3" />
    </div>
);
```

I'd like to replace this 3 `NumberInput` to render them dynamically from my endpoint list.

How to do that with react-admin:

- Call my endpoint to get the list
- Use the list to loop and create `NumberInput` dynamically

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

`react-admin` is *just* a bunch of react components. You can do this like you would in any react applications. Call `fetch` on your API in your `componentDidMount` method for example.